# javacc if statement

Tags: if-statement, javacc

I wrote if statement in javacc and do not know how to ignore if the body if the condition is false
First I declare two object class Token and boolean variable, next I check what return method condition(), next i want to skip rest of block when condition is false. How to do that?

```
void ifElse() :
            {
              Token start;
              Token next;
              boolean cond = false;
            }
            {
              {
                start = token;
              }
              < IF > < LB> cond = condition() < RB> < LP>
              {
                if (cond == false)
                {
                  String tok = (String) token.image;
                  while (tok.equals("}"))
                  {
                    token = token.next;
                  }

                }
              }
              (
                ifElse()
              | declaration()
              )*

              < RP> 
              (< ELSE > < LP> < RP >)?
            }
```

Comment: No you don't, you want to compile it. You are parsing, not executing.

Comment: @EJP Can you tell me more clearly? I know that builds a parse, but it does not work properly.

Comment: Only if you think that it should 'skip the rest of the block when the condition is false'. You are confusing parsing with execution. The parser has to process the entire program, not just the bits you like. I don't know how to put it more clearly than that.

Answer (score 1):

I've reconfigured your code, and it works almost fine. Avoids body but does not stop.

```
 `void ifElse() :
        {
          boolean cond = false;
        }
        {
          < IF > < LB> cond = condition() < RB> < LP>
          {
            if (cond == false)
            {

              while (!token.image.equals("}"))
              {
                token = getNextToken();
              }

            }
          }
          (
            ifElse()
          | declaration()
          )*

          < RP> 
          (< ELSE > < LP> < RP >)?
        }`
```